# Reindexing documents using aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, alias

The scenario is as follows :

1. Get the count of number of documents from Source ES at time T.(done using _count or cat/_count)
2. Run the reindexing. (_reindex)
3. Get the count of number of documents after time T.
4. Reindex the remaining documents using aliases after time T.

I am stuck in step 3 and i am unable to get the answer on how to find the count of number of documents after Time T. I tried range with @timestamp with gte, but it always gives 0. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Can you post your mapping and the query of range with @timestamp with gte ? Most likely, your query is wrong.